# Proper ways to use threads in TCL

Tags: multithreading, tcl

So I have the following code -

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh

package require Thread

thread::create {
    for {set i 0} {$i < 1000} {incr i} {
    puts "hello T1 $i"
    }
    thread::wait
}


thread::create {

    for {set j 0} {$j < 1000} {incr j} {
    puts "hello T2 $j"
    }
    thread::wait
}
```

It runs, but the first thread run more iterations than the loop count (1000) and the second thread has far fewer iterations than its loop count (1000 ). Can someone point out what's wrong with this code? Many thanks for your help.

Comment: It works when I try it (Tcl 8.6.9, macOS), but they very much didn't finish at the same time.

Comment: Hi Donal,  both threads count up to the loop count of 1000?

Comment: The last message from each thread are `hello T1 999` and `hello T2 999`. That looks right…

Comment: When running the script exactly as presented, the program terminates before the child threads have completed all their iterations. This could explain why you don't see all 1000 messages from T2. But I have no explanation for (and don't see) T1 running the loop more than 1000 times.

Comment: You can delay the termination of the script by adding `after 2000` at the end. Then both child threads get the chance to finish their jobs.

Comment: Thanks, will try you suggestion (after 2000)